# How can I group parts of a class partition key with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

We have a collection of Page classes called rowData. I need to group these classes by substrings of a column called `PartitionKey`.

```
  var a = from Page in rowData
        group Page by new { 
        Page.PartitionKey.Substring(0,2),
        Page.PartitionKey.Substring(2,6),
        Page.PartitionKey.Substring(8)
        } into group
    select new {
        group.key.SubjectId
        , group.key.bookId
        , group.Key.chapterId
        , total = rowData.sum(s => s.Page)
    };
```

We tried this suggestion but it gives an error:

```
Error   1   Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.
```

Does anyone have any idea what we're doing wrong?

What's needed from this is to create data for a report. The data should show the count of books, chapters and pages for each subject. Our records look like the following:

```
Primary key (columns 0-1 show the subject)
Primary key (columns 2-6 show the book ID)
Primary key (columns 8-12 show the chapter ID)
Row Key < there is a unique key for each row
```

So the combination of Primary key and the row is unique and represents a single page.

Here's an example of the primary key:

```
010000100001
010000100001
010000100001
010000100002
010000100002
010000100002
010000200003
010000200003
020000300004
020000300005
```

In this example we need a report that looks something like this:

```
Subject    Books    Chapters    Pages

01         2           3          8
02         1           2          2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, now you've clarified the question, I believe you *actually* only want to group by subject. I suspect you want something like:

```
var a = from page in rowData
        select new {
            SubjectId = Page.PartitionKey.Substring(0,2),
            BookId = Page.PartitionKey.Substring(2,6),
            ChapterId = Page.PartitionKey.Substring(8)
        } into split
        group split by split.SubjectId into g
        select new {
            SubjectId = g.Key,
            Books = g.GroupBy(x => x.BookId).Count(),
            Chapters = g.GroupBy(x => x.ChapterId).Count(),
            Pages = g.Count()
        };
```

Does that look right?

---

**Original answer**

You need to specify property names in the anonymous type:

```
var a = from page in rowData
        group page by new { 
            SubjectId = Page.PartitionKey.Substring(0,2),
            BookId = Page.PartitionKey.Substring(2,6),
            ChapterId = Page.PartitionKey.Substring(8)
        } into g
        select new {
            g.Key.SubjectId,
            g.Key.BookId,
            g.Key.ChapterId,
            Total = g.Sum(s => s.PageNumber)
        };
```

(You'll need to check the `Sum` arguments - it's not clear what you were trying to do there.)

Comment: Thanks Jon. Yes it does now fail on the Total line. What we need is to do a report that shows for each Subject the total number of books, the total number of chapters and the total number of pages. I updated the question a bit more to explain what is needed.

Comment: @RichardM: It's still not really clear what you're trying to sum. Do you actually just want a count of the number of elements in that group? If so, just use `g.Count()`

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't very clear so I updated the question. I will add an example also.

Comment: @RichardM: Okay, see my edit (at the start of the answer). If the "key" in your row is just SubjectId, that's what you need to be grouping by.

Comment: Sorry for the delay getting back to you. Tried it out and I am getting an error saying there is a missing semicolon after the "select {". Note that I did add a trailing semicolon to your solution.

Comment: @RichardM: Yes, there was a missing semi-colon before - and a missing "new". I've fixed both now.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Just before my VS2010 crashed and the size of my controller went to 0 bytes I was able to see it worked. Now have to get back to an older version. First time for me to completely lose all contents of a file like that in a while.

Answer (score 2):

Your group key needs member-names:

```
  var a = from Page in rowData
    group Page by new { 
    S1 = Page.PartitionKey.Substring(0,2),
    S2 = Page.PartitionKey.Substring(2,6),
    S3 = Page.PartitionKey.Substring(8)
    } into group
    select new {
    group.key.S1
    , group.key.S2
    , group.Key.S3
    , total = rowData.sum(s => s.Page)
};
```

And I wouldn't use `group` for a name here, better call it `into g` or something.